# Program with shortcuts to rewind set intervals or play audio at specific point in time

Tags: audio, transcription

I'm doing a large set of audio transcripts for the [Writing Excuses podcast](http://writingexcuses.com). I'm frustrated that I can't type quite as fast as people are able to talk, and therefore am forced to constantly stop and go back in the audio about 10 seconds at a time.

Basically, I'd like some application with a keyboard shortcut I could use, which would rewind the audio by a fixed amount in time, and would allow easy keyboard shortcut controlled starting and stopping of that audio.

Does such a thing exist? I know most any player supports the start and stop bit, but the "jump back 10 seconds" bit is something I've not seen before.

Comment: What OS are you planning to do this on?

Comment: @Mark: Windows or Linux would work. Windows is preferable though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**VLC**](http://www.videolan.org/) (multi-platform) has this.  You can press CTRL, ALT or SHIFT + Left/Right Arrow keys to jump backwards and forwards by different amounts, all of which are customisable in the program options.  The spacebar toggles pause.

Also, [**Foobar2000**](http://www.foobar2000.org/) (Windows) allows this (with different time intervals), once you assign the keyboard shortcuts.